# How to show amchart 4 using laravel api URL

Tags: json, laravel, api, url, amcharts4

Hello I'm trying to change my charts from amchart 3 to amchart 4, i'm using laravel 5.7 Api. the problem is when i'm trying to get graph from my laravel's api url the graph is showing "unable to load file: my laravel's url"

```
<script>
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();


chart.dataSource.url = "http://192.168.43.137/sisperdes/grafik-idm/";
chart.dataSource.parser = "JSONParser";
.....
```

is anyone can help for this problem?

Comment: If you look at your network requests in devtools, what do you see when it tries to load your laravel url?

Comment: it show my array data.

finally I used version 3 again

Answer (score 0):

you can parse to json with

```
chart.dataSource.parser = new am4core.JSONParser();
```